# can I cut this code in half?

Tags: php

I am having a php form, and a lot of markup, so i need to repeat the same form for creating a new page entry and same for editing, so for example what am doing right now is

```
if($_GET['page'] == 'hello') {
   //A whole lot of markup goes here
   <form method="post">
     <input type="text" name="whatever" />
     <input type="submit" name="create_new" />
   </form>
} elseif ($_GET['page'] == 'edit_hello') {
   //Same form markup is here, only change is the retrieved 
   //data values are echo'ed out in respective fields
   $query = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query(...));
   <form method="post">
     <input type="text" name="whatever" value="<?php echo $query['column_name']; ?>" />
     <input type="submit" name="create_new" />
   </form>
}
```

So any idea how can I use the same code for creating new entry as well as updating the form values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable and give it a default value of an empty string.

```
if($_GET['page'] == 'hello') {
   $whatever = "";
} elseif ($_GET['page'] == 'edit_hello') {
   $query = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query(...));
   $whatever = $query['column_name'];
}

<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="whatever"
      value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($whatever); ?>" />
   <input type="submit" name="create_new" />
</form>
```

Note that I've also added proper escaping for you, so that you can avoid XSS attacks.

Comment: oh ya this is a way i can go for..anything i'l miss or i'll end up in trouble if i use this? +1

Comment: This is how i do it as well. It's probably the cleanest approach.

Comment: I always use htmlspecialchars, entities as well as real_escape_string, so no issue of sanitizing the data, as well as I also track the values which are retrieved in GET

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested)

```
$value = '';

if ($_GET['page'] == 'edit_hello') $value = $query['column_name'];

if (in_array($_GET['page']), array('hello', 'edit_hello')) { ?>
<form method="post">
     <input type="text" name="whatever" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
     <input type="submit" name="create_new" />
   </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand your question right. 
You want to use the same form for create a new entry or edit, right? 
Simple way can be this for example, but there are many other ways.

If you create the form for edit mode you add an hidden field on it. After post request of the form you can check for this variable. 
Remenber: You need for update some keys, so you can update the right database record.

```
if (isset($_POST["variable"]))
{
//updateaction
}
else 
{ //insertaction 
}
```

Kind Regards